# Android layout not showing properly

Tags: android, xml, gridview, android-layout

I'm writing an android app and in it I want to have a sort of title bar including the name of the game, the score, and things like that. Then below that I want to have an grid of image views, which will kind of be like tiles on which I can display different characters in my game.

I have the following xml layout, but when I run it and I get a black screen:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/score"
            />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="0"
            />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/robotsLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/robots"
            />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="0"
            />

</LinearLayout>

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

GridView is initialized as per this tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

ie. in my main activity's onCreate():

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView(R.layout.main);          
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

Can anyone see anything I've done wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's invalid XML, because there's no root element. Also, all of your `TextView` widgets have `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`, which is rather strange. You might also consider using [`hierarchyviewer`](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html) to examine your layout more closely and see what else may be going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was just dumb and had my game loop starting form onCreate(), but the layout wasn't being rendered until after onCreate() I guess? Anyways, solved by making my my class with the game loop a Runnable

Comment: @Kalypso: Correct -- until you return control to Android, your UI will not be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

you should put a (linear)layout underneath them, as your xml is invalid.